# Scrollspy not highlighting nav links

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sass, pug, scrollspy

So I'm just making a mockup web template and would like active nav links to change upon scroll position. I was looking at using javascript but instead have moved to scroll spy as it seems simple enough.

However this is my first time using bootstrap and I cannot seem to get scroll spy to work and have looked online for hours through other related topics and cant seem to find the issue and believe I may be overlooking something simple.

help...

https://jsfiddle.net/qfsguu06/1/

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.nav', offset: 50 })

body {position: relative;}

<body>
<header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#landing">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

--edit-------------

so now i have this (i will just post with pug and sass code as that's what im using) but still not working and i cant wrap my head around it.

```
body(data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50")
  header
  nav
    ul(class="navbar")
      li(class="active")
        a(href="#landing") Home
      li
        a(href="#portfolio") Portfolio  
      li
        a(href="#about") About
      li
        a(href="#contact") Contact

body
  position: relative

.navbar
  position: fixed
  display: flex
  justify-content: flex-end
  list-style: none
  padding: 2rem 1rem
  width: 95%
li
  padding: 0 1rem

.navbar li
  a:hover
  color: black
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out
  font-weight: bold

.active
  a
  color: black
  font-weight: bold
  transition: all .3s linear
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is missing some attributes in `body` tag, Also try to use `nav` tag instead of `header`

> Add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element that should be used as the
>   scrollable area (often this is the `<body>` element).
>
> Then add the data-target attribute with a value of the id or the class
>   name of the navigation bar (`.navbar`). This is to make sure that the
>   navbar is connected with the scrollable area.
>
> Scrollspy requires `position: relative;` on the element you’re spying
>   on, usually the `<body>`.

Check below full example (Please run in **Full page** for a clear result)

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

#landing {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}

#portfolio {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #1E88E5;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#about {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}

#contact {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #1E88E5;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">C.S Photography</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#landing">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="landing" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Catrina Shellenberg Photography</h1>
    <h1>Catrina Shellenberg Photography</h1>
    <h1>Catrina Shellenberg Photography</h1>
    <h1>Catrina Shellenberg Photography</h1>
    <h1>Catrina Shellenberg Photography</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
    <h3>About</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <h4>Contact</h4>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Check links for more details

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that the body position is relative, I already linked the bodys attributes in JS, but even taking it out of JS and popping it directing in the html it still does not work. I have thoroughly checked both links and your snippet and i cant see any difference to mine.